# Losing a column when merging data frames pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-level issue. There are two tables:

Table 1 Sample Info:

```
Sample Compound Label Abundance
 1     ABC      0      10
 1     ABC      1      50
 2     ABC      0      100
 2     ABC      0      5
 3     ABC      0      100
 4     ABC      0      5
 1     DEF      0      10
 1     DEF      1      50
 1     DEF      2      100
 2     DEF      0      5
 3     DEF      0      100
 3     DEF      1      5
```

Table 2 Cohort Info:

```
Sample Cohort 
 1     control  
 2     control     
 3     disease     
 4     disease
```

I have three tasks: a) sum total abundances for each Sample in Table 1 to yield something like this

```
Sample Compound Sum_Abundance
 1     ABC           60
 2     ABC           105
 3     ABC           100
 4     ABC           5
```

b) Merge these with Table 2 to have a column with cohort info:

```
Sample Compound Sum_Abundance Cohort Info
 1     ABC           60       control
 2     ABC           105      control
 3     ABC           100      disease
 4     ABC           5        disease
```

c) Average Sum_Abundance for each Compound within a Cohort

```
Compound Avg_Abundance Cohort Info
   ABC           82.5       control
   ABC           57.5      disease
```

I have tried these steps:

```
pivot_table=pd.pivot_table(table1, values=['Abundance'], index=['Sample', 'Name'], aggfunc = np.sum)
print(table1.head(2))
sum_table = pd.DataFrame(pivot_table)
cohort_df = pd.DataFrame(table2)
print(cohort_df.head())
merged_df = pd.merge(sum_table, cohort_df, on = "Sample")
```

This is where it merges both frames but removes the compound column and no matter what I try, I cannot move passed that. If I put 'Name' into column, it creates a nicely looking output but I have no idea how to average the fields.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
step1 = (df1.groupby(['Sample','Compound'])
     ['Abundance'].sum()
    .reset_index(name='Sum_Abundance')
)

step2 = step1.merge(df2, on='Sample')

step3 = (step2.groupby(['Compound','Cohort'])
               ['Sum_Abundance'].mean()
              .reset_index(name='Avg_Abundance')
        )
```

Output:

```
  Compound   Cohort  Avg_Abundance
0      ABC  control           82.5
1      ABC  disease           52.5
2      DEF  control           82.5
3      DEF  disease          105.0
```

If the intermediate dataframes (`step1`, `step2`) are not needed, you can chain all of them:

```
final_df = (df1.groupby(['Sample','Compound'])
                ['Abundance'].sum()
               .reset_index(name='Sum_Abundance')
               .merge(df2, on='Sample')
               .step2.groupby(['Compound','Cohort'])
                ['Sum_Abundance'].mean()
               .reset_index(name='Avg_Abundance')
           )
```